# I keep getting params is empty or missing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error when I try and view the ingredients for a recipe, but I had it working on Friday. It says that the parameter is missing in my create action for ingredients. I know what the error is saying, but why would it suddenly do this if it was working? Here is the code:

Ingredients Controller

```
   class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :authenticate_user!
     before_action :set_recipe
     before_action :set_ingredient, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

     def index
         @ingredients = @recipe.ingredients.alphabetical
     end

    def show
       #  @ingredient = @recipe.ingredients
       #  @recipes = @recipe.imngredients.where('user' = ?, current_user.id == @recipe.user_id)
    end

    def new
      @ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.new
    end

    def create
      @ingredient = @recipe.ingredients.create(ingredients_params)
       if @ingredient.save
        redirect_to recipe_ingredients_path(@recipe, @ingredients)
       else
        render :new
       end
    end

    def destroy
       @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
       @ingredient.delete
       redirect_to recipe_ingredients_path(@recipe, @ingredients)
    end


    private
    def ingredients_params
      params.require(:ingredient).permit(:name, :recipe_id)
    end

    def set_recipe
      @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
    end

    def set_ingredient
      @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but I left my server running all weekend while not using my laptop and today my code is having significant issues and not working as it did on Friday

Comment: Please add the stacktrace for the error you are receiving.

Comment: Also which action are you having a problem with? Also can you please add the form used to send the params to this action and what params you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@ingredients` in create and destroy, but `@ingredients` is not set. Only one ingredient `@ingredient` is set (the ingredient that was created or destroyed).

If you want to see all ingredients after creating or destroying an ingredient, you don't need to pass `@ingredients`. Just use:

```
redirect_to recipe_ingredients_path(@recipe)
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.